# Does a large number of insects (black ants) around and on the grave have any significance?

Tags: animals, grave

Please clarify a concern I have developed after visiting my mother's grave. She passed recently and after visiting her grave recently I noticed an abnormally high amount of ants around it and on the grave.

Does this have any Islamic significance since the unusual amount of ants was such that I could hardly offer dua for any significant of time because they started crawling up my pants?

This naturally has been highly disturbing and led me to find out if this could be interpreted as punishment being suffered in the grave. Is that so?

Comment: AFAIK there is no textual evidence about visual queues for suffering in the grave.

Answer (score 3):

## No

It just happens that your mother is buried in a place that have [ants:](http://www.42explore.com/ants.htm)

> Ants are most numerous in warm climate regions, but they live almost everywhere on land except for extremely cold locations.

You really have to leave this idea of interpreting "bad things" as a punishment: Even though we have some Ahadith about it  nobody said that we can see such punishments.

When a person dies his body doesn't have the same value he had when he was alive. So "punishing" the body is meaningless. If you are still scared about the fate of your mother, you can read Quran and Dua for her.